# How to set the distance of the camera from a scaling object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My camera has to focus on an `GameObject` that can be scaled over time. How can I compute the camera position so that it is always at the same distance from this `GameObject`? I've already tried to do something like

```
camera.position.y += object.scaleFactor / 2;
camera.position.z -= object.scaleFactor / 2;
```

But the bigger the object becomes, the lesser it works. I'm thinking about using a bounding box, do you think it would work ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: It seems that scale factor are not linear if it does not work with bigger object. I think you must use some polynomial instead of simple expression object.scaleFactor / 2

Comment: Do you mean constant distance from the center of the Game Object or from the nearest edge of the Game Object? If you mean from the center, you can just set camera position as a constant value relative to Game Object position. If you mean from the edge of the object, you will have to calculate distance using the scale factor, where camera position is set at a constant value, multiplied by the scale of the object.

Comment: You can't modify the individual value types points on the `position` Vector3. Need to create a new Vector3 and the set the camera's position to that.

Comment: This is not the root cause of your problem but still better to fix that before moving on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
// compute this when scale is 1.0f
Vector3 originalPosition = camera.position;
Vector3 originalDistance = camera.position - gameObject.position;

// then use:
camera.position = originalPosition + originalDistance * gameObject.scaleFactor;
```

if this does not work, please describe your situation in more detail and i will edit the answer

for example: if you want that the camera keeps the distance to the object, you will have to use `BoundingSphere.radius`:

```
// compute this when scale is 1.0f
Vector3 originalPosition = camera.position;
Vector3 temp = camera.position - gameObject.position;
Vector3 originalDirection = temp.normalized;
float originalDistance = temp.magnitude - boundingSphere.radius;

// use this when object is scaled:
camera.position = originalPosition + originalDirection * (boundingSphere.radius + originalDistance);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ObjectRelativeScale : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float ObjectScale = 1.0f;
    private Vector3 _initialScale;

void Start()
{
    _initialScale = transform.localScale;
}

void Update()
{
    var cameraMainTransform = Camera.main.transform;
    var plane = new Plane(cameraMainTransform.forward, cameraMainTransform.position);
    float dist = plane.GetDistanceToPoint(transform.position);
    transform.localScale = _initialScale * dist * ObjectScale;
}
```

}

Basically the way around is better, scale the object depending on the camera position.

Cheers!